# How can I use case when in order by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample records. This records shown in below. I want to select only a process type. When I select process type I have a condition. If Max create date between this records bigger than max modify date then order by create date and select top 1 process type else if max modify date bigger than max create date order by modify date and select top 1 process type.

This is my query. I tried that query but I have an error. Process_type is invalid in the select list.

```
 select top 1
 process_type
from
#Result veh (nolock) 
where
veh.end_date is null
and veh.is_owner=0
and veh.relation_type=1
group by 
veh.fk_customer_id,
veh.fk_vehicle_id,
veh.relation_type,
veh.is_owner
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
order by 
CASE WHEN  MAX(veh.create_date)>= MAX(veh.modify_date) THEN veh.create_date ELSE veh.modify_date END desc
```

This is all records.

| pk_id | customer_id | vehicle_id | relation_type | end_date | is_owner | create_date | modify_date | process_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null | 0 | 2021-09-14 | 2021-09-13 | 4 |
| 2 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null | 0 | 2021-09-18 | 2021-09-13 | 6 |
| 3 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null | 0 | 2021-09-16 | 2021-09-13 | 5 |
| 4 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null | 0 | 2021-09-19 | 2021-09-13 | 3 |

This is expected record because this record has max create date between all records. After this expected records. I want to select process type from expected record.

| pk_id | customer_id | vehicle_id | relation_type | end_date | is_owner | create_date | modify_date | process_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 100 | 200 | 1 | null | 0 | 2021-09-19 | 2021-09-13 | 3 |

Comment: That query looks very flawed. You have `GROUP BY` on multiple columns, but only 1 in the `SELECT`. You use `NOLOCK`  on a temporary table (Why?? What other person is going to be using that table? Do you understand what `NOLOCK` does?). You're expected results have multiple columns too, yet again those aren't defined in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Your query (`and veh.relation_type=100`) does not match the output ( column `relation_type` has value `1`).   

Comment: Start splattering your code with [nolock](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). But if you do use it, **at least** use the current syntax and not the deprecated version. Use on a local temp table is just nonsense.

Comment: @SMor "**Start** splattering"? Too early for coffee/tea/drink of choice to kick in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the last row in a series of two or more rows.

```
select process_type
from (
    select *
      , row_number() over(
                 partition by fk_customer_id, fk_vehicle_id, relation_type, is_owner 
                 order by CASE WHEN create_date >= modify_date THEN create_date ELSE modify_date END DESC) rn1
      , row_number() over(
                 partition by fk_customer_id, fk_vehicle_id, relation_type, is_owner 
                 order by CASE WHEN create_date >= modify_date THEN create_date ELSE modify_date END) rn2            
    from #Result
    where  end_date is null
       and is_owner=0
       and relation_type=100
) t
where rn1 = 1 and rn2 > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the record based on the maximum of create date or modify date.  That would be:

```
select top (1) process_type
from# Result veh
where veh.end_date is null and
      veh.is_owner = 0 and
      veh.relation_type = 1
order by (case when modify_date > create_date then modify_date else create_date end)
```

If you want this per customer, then you can use `row_number()`:

```
select top (1) process_type
from (select veh.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customerid order by (case when modify_date > create_date then modify_date else create_date end)) as seqnum
      from #Result veh
      where veh.end_date is null and
            veh.is_owner = 0 and
            veh.relation_type = 1
     ) veh
where seqnum = 1;
```